# Cannot acquire lock for source node / 0

Tags: 7, feeds

This error showing when I tried to import a CSV file on my live site. Same file I tried in local site working fine.

> Cannot acquire lock for source node / 0.

The modules I am using are the following:

- Feeds
- Feed Excel
- Libraries (PHP Excel)

I examine the issue and found that the error occurred when I tried to import an image. Have anyone faced this issue?

Comment: Hello. Could you add info about modules you are using? Drupal does not provide CSV imports or node locks in core.

Comment: As side note, there isn't any Drupal node whose node ID is 0; the lower node ID is 1.

Comment: updated my question.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Its working fine in local site. I didn't set node id also. I am creating new node.

Comment: Is there a node id 0 in your database? It is possible to create it directly and it can screw up pretty many things. Like @kiamlaluno said there can't be a *valid* node with that ID, but database would allow it none the less.

Comment: @Mołot no there is not.

Comment: OK, I guess I can assume you meant the server with the problem. Now: we know locking mechanism is OK, as you cannot lock something that's non-existent. Big question is - what feeds node 0 to it?

Comment: @Mołot Can it be any library issue that is installed in my local server and not on live server?

Comment: Yes, it can. It should be simple to test, so please do test and we'll know for sure :)

Comment: @Mołot This error is occuring when I saved an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image path was not correct so the error was showing.

Answer (score 2):

To release the lock, remove it from `semaphore` table, e.g.:

```
drush sqlq "DELETE FROM semaphore WHERE name LIKE 'feeds_source_%'"
```

---

If you got different error like:

> The feed is currently importing.

then you need to clear out `state` and `fetcher_result` data from `feeds_source` table, e.g.:

```
drush sqlq "UPDATE feeds_source SET state = NULL, fetcher_result = NULL WHERE id = 'FEEDS_MACHINE_NAME' AND feed_nid = 'NID'"
```

<sup>Note: Change `FEEDS_MACHINE_NAME` and `NID` into appropriate values.</sup>